# PowerShell Remoting using SOAP from Java

Tags: java, soap, powershell, exchange-server, remoting

First let me say I am no expert in PowerShell. In my project I need to invoke remote Exchange server PS Commands from Java application.
 
PS remoting is supposed to expose SOAP api (WSMan), but I couldn't find any sample how to connect using generic SOAP client (like SoapUI), or Java.
Questions are: 
Can I connect to WSMan endpoint using SOAP over HTTP? 
What is the endpoint URL like? 
Can I authenticate to service using Basic Authentication? 
Does this service expose mex endpoint (where I can get WSDL from)? 
What is the syntax for the SOAP request doing something simple like "Get-User"?
Thanks
Boris

Comment: Wikipedia article mentions and links a few open source projects around porting WS-Management. Not sure on the maturity/completeness on any of them though. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Management

Comment: Well it doesn't help much. I need specifics about PowerShell wsman endpoint: address, protocol, authentication, etc.. Once I figure that out, I don't need third party WS-Management implementation, I can write my own using JAX-WS, Axis, or plain XML over HTTP.